# Youtube api viewcount field linq c#

Tags: linq, youtube, youtube-api

I have these code snippets ( razor / c# ) that gets a list of youtube videos. I need to get the viewcount field though, how would I get this?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/BBC/uploads");

XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
XNamespace yt = "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007";

var items = xDoc.Descendants(media + "group")
                .Select(i=>new{
                    Title = i.Element(media + "title").Value,
                    Content = i.Element(media + "content").Attribute("url").Value,
                    Thumbnail = i.Element(media + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
            Category = i.Element(media + "category").Value
                })
                .ToList();

var items2 = xDoc.Descendants(media + "group").Descendants(yt + "uploaded")
                .Select(i=>new{
                    Uploaded = i.Element(yt + "uploaded").Value
                })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the response you're looking for, but I'd recommend using JSON instead of XML, and parsing the JSON response instead of dealing with XML.

E.g. you can request https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/BBC/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&prettyprint=true to get back the equivalent feed in JSON.

The view count data is in items[i]->viewCount, and the other pieces of metadata you want are there as well.

Comment: Great idea.  I'll try JSON!